# (Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileInfo + Powershell + File > 1gb) = Boom

Tags: .net, file-io, amazon-s3, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to upload files to Amazon S3. Works well, as long as the files don't exceed 1GB in size.
If so, Powershell runs into some Memory Loop when it processes the 1st byte after 1 GB and never makes it to my write-host line
I just can't figure out why there's a limit and how to handle that. Any ideas?

(Code snippet below opens a file stream Reader + writer. The real code for this function on my home computer contains an additional cryptostream writer, which I removed here for the sake of readability of the code, just in case someone's wondering what the code should be good for. Result however is the same -> Memory Loop)

```
function S3Upload()
{
   $FileStreamWriter = (New-Object Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileInfo($S3Client, $BucketName, $key)).OpenWrite()  
   $FileStreamReader = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($SourceFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)    

  [int16]$Bytes2read = 16
  [Byte[]]$Data  = New-Object Byte[] 16
  Do{      
     $Count   = $FileStreamReader.Read($Data, 0, $Bytes2read)
     $FileStreamWriter.Write($Data, 0, $Count)    
    }
  While ($Count -gt 0)

  write-host "Closing Streams"
  $FileStreamReader.Close()
  $FileStreamWriter.Close() 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [S3FileInfo](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_IO_S3FileInfo.htm) to write to a stream does not work well for large files. All the data is needed for computing the signature to S3 so the S3FileInfo buffers the data written to its streams until the stream is closed.

I would suggest using the [TransferUtility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility.htm) and use the `Upload(stream, bucketName, key)` method that takes in your stream, see [Using the High-Level .NET API for Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuDotNet.html) for details and example snippets.

Since you are using a Crypto stream you might want to take a look at the S3 encryption support added to version 2 of the SDK, see [Client Side Data Encryption with AWS SDK for .NET and Amazon S3](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/TxL15A0QZMD38D/Client-Side-Data-Encryption-with-AWS-SDK-for-NET-and-Amazon-S3).

Comment: Thanks Norm for your answer, I guess I have to rework my code here.